# Loop values in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am using nextjs, React and Typescript. I want to loop out values from an array of objects. My

data.json:

```
[
    {
      "id": "value”,
      “name": “value”, 
      “type”: “value”
    },
    {
      "id": “value”,
      “name": “value”, 
      “type": “value”
    }
]
```

cars.map is not a function.

Comment: I didn't understand what stops you from iterate over the `cars` array. Why can't you do something like `cars.map(car => Object.keys(car) ...)`?

Comment: I  get the data but mapping it gives ".map is not a function"

Comment: Ok, so maybe you need to do `JSON.parse(cars)` then you should have a real array.

Comment: as easy as that thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Everything in your code appears to be properly typed.  If you want to display values from your Cars array, you could `map` over the `cars` array, similarly to:

```
const IndexPage: NextPage<{ cars: Cars[] }> = ({ cars }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>IndexPage</h1>
      {cars.map(car => <div key={car.id}>{car.name}: {car.type}</div>)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

An array of React JSX generated by a map function need to have unique keys added on the parent tag of the map output.  See [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) for more detail.  For more detail on Map, see [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: {cars} shows me the data but cars.map gives undefined

Comment: When you say `cars` shows you the data, what variable type is it?  If `cars` is truly an array, `cars.map` would not be undefined.  Be sure you are copying the code as-is above, not wrapping the <div> with the car values in curly brackets.

Comment: typeof(cars) is a string!

Comment: JSON.parse(cars) should give you an JSON array you need.

Comment: amazing thank you!